# Input range, haw to add dynamically max value in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input

I am making the app with audio files. Using input range, i want to let people to get in any part of audio file. But for some reasons my input range is shorter than duration of audio files. How can I make input range flexible, so that it can get adapted to any duration of song ?

```
       <div>
            <button onClick={()=>setIsPlaying(true)}>start</button>
            <button onClick={()=>setIsPlaying(false)}>stop</button>
            <h3>Current time:{currentTime}</h3>
            <h3>Duration of song: {durationOfSong} </h3>
            <input type="range"  max={durationOfSong}  /* here i want to declare the max width of my input, getting duration of song, but it just does not see it */} className="range" onChange={onChange}
      </div>
```

Comment: use codesandbox and put your code there, hard to know without knowing your full data

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-lumiere-ju875u?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question `durationOfSong` should be a [**props**](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for this component or an [**state**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), and as a result your component will re-render each time this prop or state is changed. A good practice is to pass this duration as a prop to your component after you fetched your data in the parent component.

Comment: Yes, I did it, just the problem is different. I dont understand how to customize my input range with max value. I try to put durrationOfSong in "max" from state, it is 3.05 seconds, but the result 1,45 second the length of input.

Comment: Your sandbox is not working, I might be able to help if you show me what is wrong and what you mean by customizing it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-ellis-mu96nx?file=/src/timer.tsx fixed

Comment: The main problem that my input is shorter than the duration of song.